# Which version of Internet Explorer does this screenshot display

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, html, compatibility, web-development

I have a client whose browser renders my webpage really badly (and slowly).

The image below is cut out from a screenshot he sent me. I know it is IE, but can anyone see which version? And if it is running in compatibility mode?

If it is running in compatibility mode - what could be the reason for him to do so?

[image: Image of browser]

Comment: Why can't you ask them to do "help > about" and read the version number from there?

Comment: Ive asked, will revert with correct answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic theme?! My eyes!

Looks like IE 8. I set my theme to classic and IE 8 looks exactly like that. Also it looks like the compatibility view button is "pressed" next to the address bar and lock icon.

What you have here is

- IE 8 (or 7; though I'm definitely leaning 8) running inside of a Citrix XenApp instance (basically desktop virtualization)
- Compatibility mode to IE 6 (?)
- Classic theme

Under these conditions it's going to be horribly slow and broken. Tell the client to stop using this browser, or at the very least, stop using compatibility mode. They may not have enabled it intentionally; it could be because they have other websites that need it and it's just defaulted to enabled everywhere.

P.S. - Yes, I still have IE 8 installed, but it's not by choice, as I don't own this computer. I use Chrome as my main browser, though. :}

Comment: Or just stop using Citrix, ouch! IE8 was not bad, IE9 /10 is GREAT! But Citrix is the worst!

Answer (score 1):

From what I see as the forward and back buttons style, this is Internet Explorer 7 or 8. I get the overall feeling that it is IE 7 though.

I am going to say that this IS... Internet Explorer 7.

I hope this helps.